# Convert 2 arrays x 3 key=> value to become 3 arrays x 2 [ index] value

Tags: php

I have this 2 arrays x 3 key=>value:

```
$a = array ( [PLTS] => 400 [SCMT] => 300 [PROG] => 100 ) 
$b = array ( [PLTS] => 800 [SCMT] => 400 [PROG] => 200 )
```

I want to convert it to 3 arrays x 2 index value like this:

```
$PLTS = array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 800)
$SCMT = array ( [0] => 300 [1] => 400 ) 
$PROG = array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 200 )
```

How can I do it??

Comment: What did you try so far ? Is there a problem you encountered ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the general process.  Build an array of the arrays and extract each column into a new var:

```
$PLTS = array_column(array($a, $b), 'PLTS');
$SCMT = array_column(array($a, $b), 'SCMT');
$PROG = array_column(array($a, $b), 'PROG');
```

To do all arrays in one:

```
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    ${$k} = array_column(array($a, $b), $k);
}
```

However, I would go for a result array:

```
foreach($a as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = array_column(array($a, $b), $k);
}
```

Comment: That's a fresh idea.

Comment: In your second (and third) example you should probably move the array() part outside the loop. Your recreating the same array on each iteration. apart from that +1

Answer (score 1):

> Here is the general process. Build an array of the arrays and extract
>   each column into a new var:

Given your two arrays:

```
$a=array("PLTS"=>400,"SCMT"=>300,"PROG"=>100);
$b=array("PLTS"=>800,"SCMT"=>400,"PROG"=>200);
```

You can achieve it in only one foreach loop with this write less do more code:

```
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    extract(array($k=>array($v,$b[$k])));
}
```

it exactly create what you were expecting:

> ```
> $PLTS = array ( [0] => 400 [1] => 800) $SCMT = array ( [0] => 300 [1]
> => 400 )  $PROG = array ( [0] => 100 [1] => 200 )
> ```